# WCF generated stub does not generate correct return type

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization

I have a WCF client-server setup. On the server side I am using interfaces as return types in my service methods and then attributing my contracts/services with the `<ServiceKnownTypeAttribute>`. All this is working fine.

There is, however, one issue that is quite annoying. When I add a service reference to my client, the generated stub methods all have a return type of `object`. Hence, Intellisense is no longer existing on my client. I am fully able to use the return values and can access the properties, but I have to do a cast to be able to "restore" Intellisense.

Example:

server method:

```
<OperationContract()>
<ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(GetType(Something))>
Function GetSomething() As ISomething Implements Iservice.GetSomething
```

generated stub:

```
Function GetSomething() As Object Implements Iservice.GetSomething
```

client code (must do cast here as stub return type is object):

```
Dim s As ISomething= CType(client.GetSomething(), ISomething)
```

Am I missing something or is this just normal behaviour. As the objects can be serialized and all is working I cant understand why my stub is not type specific.

Thanks

Jonas

Comment: How would you serialize an interface?  What would the client do with an interface (i.e., how would it implement it?)  Interfaces are an OO concept - WCF (and web services) are about SOA and don't understand OOP.  Google "Return interface from WCF" and you'll see lots of answers about this and *why* it can't be done (or at least, not very easily).

Comment: I think your are missing my point. Let me try to be clearer.

Comment: I think your are missing my point. Let me try to be clearer. I am not trying to return an interface. I am, however, using interfaces on the server side and then telling the serializer about the concrete types. I do that using attributes on my methods/services. This way serializer knows how to serialize interface return types into concrete implementation. Again, all the code in my post is working. This way I can continue using interfaces on the client. I hope this is sufficient for you to see that is is NOT a serialization issue.

Comment: I'm still not understanding you. "On the server side I am using interfaces as return types" - how is this not returning an interface?  Is `ISomething` an interface?  If it is, then `Function GetSomething() As ISomething` is returning an interface.  I'm not disagreeing with you - I'm just not seeing what you seem to be trying to tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what's going on, and I'll try to give an explanation, though some of it is an educated guess.

First, I'm going to make a guess that you're actually generating a concrete type that implements `ISomething` from the function, but you're returning the interface rather than the object.  Assume `MySomething` implements `ISomething` and it might look like this:

```
Function GetSomething() As ISomething Implements Iservice.GetSomething

    ' code to create the object
    Return MySomething
End Function
```

If you were to call this in something like a console app, you'd probably do this:

```
Dim MySomething As ISomething = GetSomething()
```

Now here's where I'm making an educated guess.

WCF will generate the proxy based on the interface for the service contract.  Since the service contract's operation contract is returning an interface as opposed to a concrete class, it uses `Object` to generate a concrete implementation so the data can be serialized over the wire.

Since the client doesn't know the `Object` in this case is implementing `ISomething`, I don't see any other way to "restore" Intellisense other than casting `Object` to `ISomething`.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for your response. I am also guessing that this is the case. However, the client does know about both the concrete implementation and the interface as these types are referenced and used by my client through "Reuse types in referenced assemblies". Serialization goes on "under the hood" and is, of course, done on concrete types. The generated stub, however, could very well return ISomething as the return type and the serialization process are 2 different things (or at least I hope that they designed it this way). By now I am thinking that this is just another design decision..

Comment: @Flodpanter - I think that it might be a case of even though both the client and the service know about the concrete implementation and the interfaces, they may be viewed as different because they are in the separate assemblies.  Again, not 100% sure - I work with `ChannelFactory<T>` and shared assemblies - haven't used service references in quite some time, so there may be some slight differences.  Can you verify in your code if the namespaces for the objects are different between the service and the client?