# WCF client dismisses collection type

Tags: c#, wcf

My WCF service contains an operation like this:

```
void Provide(IEnumerable<IMyInterface>);
```

I have made a service reference on my client and selected `IEnumerable` as the type for collections.

The problem is when I try to invoke this method on the client with an `ObservableCollection` of type `IMyInterface` it fails because the method's signature miraculously became:

```
void Provide(IEnumerable<object>);
```

So basically the service reference dismissed the type of my collection.
I thought this was because `IMyInterface` wasn't contracted but it turns out you can't make a `DataContract` out of an interface.

Comment: You'll need to use a concrete class for the type of IEnumerable.  Or, if your client is aware of `IMyInterface`, you can cast the result back to `IMyInterface`.

Comment: Isn't it possible for the DataContractSerializer to serialize an interface?

Comment: No, it's not.  An interface is a contract that tells the implementing class what properties/methods it must contain.  In and of itself an interface does not contain data, so how would the system serialize it?  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/18757619/745969 for a similar discussion on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I edited the auto-generated Reference.cs file and changed the method signatures.

Comment: Editing auto-generated files is a **very** bad idea.  What happens if you make a change to the service and you forget to change the auto-generated file, or someone else makes a change and doesn't realize they need to change the auto-generated file?  Instead of trying to force the framework to do what you want it to do, its better to figure out a way to do what you're trying to do within the capabilities of the framework.